# How do I throw a tv4 error with a message?

Tags: javascript, json, error-handling

The data schema below has an error in it and there is an object present for the test that fails validation. I can throw the error but there's no error message.

```
var tv4 = require('tv4')

var schema = {
 "items": {
   "type": "boolean"
 }
}

tv4.setErrorReporter(function (error, data, schema) {
  return "Custom error message"
})

var data1 = [true, false]
var data2 = [true, 123]

console.log(tv4.validate(data1, schema))
if (tv4.error) throw tv4.error
console.log(tv4.validate(data2, schema))
if (tv4.error) throw tv4.error
```

The message still has no error message.

```
Error
    at new ValidationError (/project/node_modules/tv4/tv4.js:1461:12)
    at ValidatorContext.createError (/project/node_modules/tv4/tv4.js:359:14)
    at ValidatorContext.validateType (/project/node_modules/tv4/tv4.js:751:14)
    at ValidatorContext.validateBasic (/project/node_modules/tv4/tv4.js:721:19)
    at ValidatorContext.validateAll (/project/node_modules/tv4/tv4.js:599:19)
    at ValidatorContext.validateArrayItems (/project/node_modules/tv4/tv4.js:947:21)
    at ValidatorContext.validateArray (/project/node_modules/tv4/tv4.js:880:11)
    at ValidatorContext.validateAll (/project/node_modules/tv4/tv4.js:602:11)
    at Object.api.validate (/project/node_modules/tv4/tv4.js:1573:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (tv4-test.js:20:17)
```

How can I throw an invalid schema with a message?

Comment: you don't, it clearly already throws inside the tv4 API. Just catch the error and then throw it on if you need to: `try { tv4.validate(...); } catch(e) { ... }`

Comment: The `.validate` function is returning a boolean for me. It's not throwing.

Comment: you don't throw "a thing" you throw errors, so you need to get the relevant data out of `tv4.error` and then `throw new Error("something stringy")` with the information you need, like [tv4.error.message](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tv4#usage-1-simple-validation). That said, throwing is generally a terrible idea, because you want to know about *all* failures, not just "the first" and then spend a day fixing them one by one. That would be horrible.

Comment: `tv4.error` is indeed not a 'thing' it's an error object. The message attached should be the message that is thrown. As long as the other `subErrors` are in the object I can use them to respond a list of errors to the user.

Comment: no, my point was that you don't throw "arbitrary things", if you want to throw propertly, you need to throw an actual error object, using `new Error("...")`. Throwing whatever happens to be in `tv4.error` won't work, so given the API docs, you want to `throw new Error(tv4.error.message)`

Answer (score 3):

Thank you this saved almost half of my lyf :), Thank you people
and for others always use these 3 lines for schema test:

```
  console.log(" Schema Valid " +JSON.stringify(tv4.validate(jsonData ,schema)));
  console.log("Validation errors: "+ tv4.error);
  console.log(tv4.error.dataPath);
```

and output will be like :

**LOGGS**

```
false
Validation errors: ValidationError: Invalid type: string (expected integer)
/guardVerificationUrl
```

In addition if you want to know what type of error use:

```
console.log(tv4.error.schemaPath);
```

Output :

```
/properties/guardVerificationUrl/type
```